# Different ways to select disabled option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem which deals with selecting an option element. In the shop I maintain there is an old script which selects **disabled** option element this way:

```
$(this).find('....., .bundle-article select option:selected');
```

And that works. From some reason in a new theme, which has bootstrap 4 instead of bootstrap 3 and newer jquery, that .find() does not select the desired element. But if I do:

```
$(this).find('#some-id-of-that-option-tag');
```

pointing to the same element as the previous selector I get the result I need. But from some reasons, it is better not to change script I did not write.

I am not a JS developer and I need help or advice on how to solve this. Is there some change how jquery selects disabled elements in diff versions?

html:

```
<div class="bundle-article config-option">
  <select name="grundbauteil-7-ankerplatte" id="select-grundbauteil-7-ankerplatte" class="form-control" >
    <option id="product-2764" value="2764" selected="selected" disabled>
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: It would be very useful if you would provide us with the relevant HTML code to the question.

Comment: Try this way and check if it works or not i.e : `$(this).find('.....,.bundle-article select option[disabled]:selected')`

Comment: People thanx for trying to help, I found it deals with .selectpicker('refresh') so it definitely is not what I asked.